# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 - JSON AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, json

I need your help in fixing this error.

Below is the js code for a custom plugin in wordpress which allows the users to select the products from different categories on a single custom page. Somehow it stopped working and shows error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0" in the console but the data seems to be loading.

```
//Ajax form
function ajaxForm(){
    $(document).on('submit','.ajax-form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).find('.byp-backdrop,.byp-loader').fadeIn();
        var formData = new FormData(this),turl;
        if((turl = $(this).attr('action'))!=='') turl = window.location.href;
        $.ajax({
            url: turl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).always(function(data){
            responser($.parseJSON(data));
            $(document).find('.byp-backdrop, .byp-loader').fadeOut();
        });
    });
}
function responser(data){
    if(data[0]==0){ //Messager
        $(document).find(data[1]).html(data[2]);
    }else if(data[0]==1){ //FadeOut
        $(document).find(data[1]).fadeOut();
    }else if(data[0]==2){ //FadeIn
        $(document).find(data[1]).fadeIn();
    }else if(data[0]==3){ //SlideUp
        $(document).find(data[1]).slideUp();
    }else if(data[0]==4){ //SlideDown
        $(document).find(data[1]).slideDown();
    }else if(data[0]==5){ //RemoveClass
        $(document).find(data[1]).removeClass(data[2]);
    }else if(data[0]==6){ //AddClass
        $(document).find(data[1]).addClass(data[2]);
    }else if(data[0]==7){ //DataTag
        $(document).find(data[1]).attr(data[2],data[3]);
    }else if(data[0]==8){ //Redirect
        window.location.href = data[1];
    }else if(data[0]==9){ //MultiRequest
        $.each(data[1],function(k,v){
            responser(v);
        });
    }else if(data[0]==10){ //DestroyResource
        $(document).find(data[1]).remove();
    }else if(data[0]==11){ //AddResource
        $(document).find(data[1]).append(data[2]);
    }
}


//Build Your PC Section
function byp(){
    var bypwait = 0, bypurl, bypinterval;
    $(document).on('click','.byp-radio',function(){
        $(document).find('.byp-backdrop, .byp-loader').fadeIn();
        var component = $(this).attr('id').split('-'),fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('ajax-request','byp');
        fd.append('component',component[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: fd,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).always(function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            responser($.parseJSON(data));
            $(document).find('.byp-backdrop, .byp-loader').fadeOut();
        });
        var sels = $(document).find('.byp-radio.selected .byp-product-price'),p,t=0;
        $.each(sels,function(k,v){
            p = $(this).html().substring(2,$(this).html().length);
            t += parseInt(p);
        });
```

Could someone kindly help me with this issue or atleast give an idea how to debug the same.

Comment: fyi: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Debugging is easy: open the dev tools in your browser (F12) and check the reply. Not sure what would make it start with an `A` though)

Comment: @ChrisG Hi.... Thanks for your reply... i have done that already and the data is flowing what exactly is required but it starts with the word array and not just the json []